# Error in browser when i run my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

"I only get an error in browser, This the Error" :

Unexpected Application Error!
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `Layout`.

```
    createFiberFromTypeAndProps@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39715:21
    createFiberFromElement@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39738:46
    createChild@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26685:54
    reconcileChildrenArray@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26982:40
    reconcileChildFibers@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:27396:20
reconcileChildren@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31573:32
updateHostComponent$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32287:24
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33945:18
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38731:18
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37929:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37843:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37812:11
recoverFromConcurrentError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37221:38
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37122:26
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48787:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48761:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49045:25
```

Hey developer

You can provide a way better UX than this when your app throws errors by providing your own ErrorBoundary prop on

"I've been trying and try to find the solution in chatGPT but still get the same error in my browser, i hope anyone here can help and give me a solution for this problem"

"This is Layout component code" :

```
import React from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Navbar />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

this is my App.js file :

```
import React from "react";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home/Home";
import Product from "./pages/Product/Product";
import Products from "./pages/Products/Products";
import Layout from "./Components/Layout/Layout";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/products/:id",
        element: <Products />,
      },
      {
        path: "/product/:id",
        element: <Product />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

This is Navbar.js :

```
import React from 'react'

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

this is footer.js :

```
import React from 'react'

function Footer() {
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

Comment: Can you share your `Layout` component code?

Comment: Yes, i put Layout component code above...

Comment: Are `Navbar` and `Footer` components default exports from their respective files? Is `Layout` default imported for use on the `element` prop of the `Route` it's on? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] that includes all relevant code you are working with?

Comment: yes navbar, footer components default exports from their respective files, and Layout imported for use on the element prop of the Route it's on

Comment: Can you add these complete files to the post so we can see for ourselves?  If that's all correct and accurate, can you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the error that we could inspect live?

Comment: Thank you @RahmatHidayat. Can you share your file structure as well?

Comment: in my VSCode terminal i don't get any error at all, but in my browser show up an error like above..

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese. but where can i share my file structure?

Comment: devpolo requested the file structure, it can be formatted text snippet in the post. If you create a sandbox we'd be able to see that structure as well, though that might not be an exact match of your *actual* code organization. I think devpolo is fishing to see if perhaps an import path is incorrect.

Comment: i add my App.js file above, so you guys can see my code...

Comment: The error seems to be in the `Layout` component. Can you add the navbar and footer files. Comment both of these components out to see if the app renders, and if so, uncomment one, then the other, to see which is the issue. Then look into *that* component and repeat the process to see where the app code is breaking.

Comment: oke i'll add navbar and footer code too

Comment: i'm pretty sure my code is right and i'm not made a mistake

Comment: See if you can copy/paste your code into a running codesandbox and reproduce the error such that we can also inspect it live.

Comment: @DrewReese yes i created the project on sanbox, can you give your email so i can invite you

Comment: Sharing a link here should be sufficient.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-estrela-fhzuf7

Comment: Did you make sure to include/save all the files? There is no `src/pages` directory so some component imports are failing.

Comment: yes i did, i'm sure i include/save all the files

Comment: in sandbox i didn't get any error in the sandbox browser, but why in VScode and my browser i get an error like an error i put above

Comment: Then there remains still *something* different with the code/project on your local machine than what you created in the sandbox.

Comment: it occurs on me.And it occured in dev envirment.It's no problem with building.Last serveral days,the error disappear and show today...

Comment: while i delete a line where includes cloneDeep method from lodash,and then it's ok.Actually, i don't kown what happened and why.Perharps,it happen while state update too much.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with route. As your router says path '/' for `<Layout />` and for `<Home/>` components. Rectify the routes properly, It should work fine!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to start every path with a forward slash ('/') in the children array. Additionally, make sure that each path is unique and distinct from one another.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).